# Close login form and open main form

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I want to show firstly my login form (FrmLogin) and if user correctly put his credentials to close FrmLogin and show main form (FrmMain) therefore i did following steps:

in Application.xaml instead of StartupUri i placed:

```
 Startup="Application_Startup">
```

then in Application.xaml.vb:

```
  Class Application

        Private Sub Application_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs)

            Dim result As New FrmLogin
            result.ShowDialog()

            If (result.DialogResult.HasValue And result.DialogResult.Value) Then
                    Dim FrmMain As New FrmMain()
        Run(FrmMain)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("User clicked Cancel")
'closing application...
            End If

        End Sub


    End Class
```

in FrmLogin:

```
 Public Class FrmLogin
        Private Sub btnOk_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click
            Me.DialogResult = True
        End Sub

        Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
            Me.DialogResult = False
        End Sub
    End Class
```

unfortunetly i got errors on those lines in Applciation_Startup:

```
  Dim FrmMain As New FrmMain()
        Run(FrmMain)
```

error message:

> Additional information: Application is already running the Dispatcher.

what i am doing wrong and what should i do? By the way is this approach correct?

Comment: Whats the problem again?

Comment: i modified my post please check again

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in the Past and the way I accomplished this is as follows:

Modify App.xaml `C#` or Application.xaml `VB`:

```
<Application x:Class="LoginFormExample.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoginFormExample"
         StartupUri="winMDI.xaml" ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown" Startup="Application_Startup" >
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
```

The Key Piece is `ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"` which prevents the program from shutting down after the first window is closed, which would be your Login Window.

Next modify the App.xaml.cs like this:

```
    public partial class App : Application
{

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        winLogin login = new winLogin();
        bool? bResult = login.ShowDialog();
        if (!bResult.HasValue || !bResult.Value)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed Login");
            this.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

or Application.xaml.vb:

```
Class Application

Private Sub Application_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs)

    Dim login As New winLogin()
    Dim bResult As Nullable(Of Boolean) = login.ShowDialog()
    If Not bResult.HasValue OrElse Not bResult.Value Then
        MessageBox.Show("Failed Login")
        Shutdown()
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

And Last since `ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"` you will need to shutdown your app after your main window closes manually like this:

```
<Window x:Class="LoginFormExample.winMDI"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoginFormExample"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="winMDI" Height="300" Width="300" Closed="Window_Closed">
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

Key Piece = `Closed="Window_Closed"`

And:
`C#`

```
    public partial class winMDI : Window
{
    public winMDI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

`VB`

```
Class winMDI
Private Sub Window_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Application.Current.Shutdown()

End Sub
```

End Class

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try set FrmLogin.xaml as startup window.

```
StartupUri="FrmLogin.xaml"
```

in FrmLogin, after login succeed, create new MainWindow and Show(), then close FrmLogin.